# unit testing sync framework

Tags: unit-testing, testing, microsoft-sync-framework

We have built a custom provider for the microsoft sync framework. How would you go about unit testing it or would you not bother with the unit testing and focus on integration tests?

Answer (score 0):

I have had some success using [Moq](http://code.google.com/p/moq/) to help write unit tests for a custom provider. Unfortunately the Sync Framework hasn't been designed to make testing easy.